# How do I thank Stack Exchange users in my thesis?

Tags: discussion, thanks, citation, specific-site

I am a graduate student of mathematics. I find the math.stackexchange.com site very useful in my understanding of mathematics. (I never used the site without mentioning about it in my homework, etc.)

Now, how do I include this site in the acknowledgement part of the master's thesis?  Do I just mention the basic site name? Do I need to include the web address in the references part? There is no specific usage throughout the thesis. However, during taking lessons I benefited a lot from this site.

Comment: This has been discussed on Academia [How to acknowledge ideas/clue/discussions on StackExchange?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/16047/61561)